# jQuery function conversion

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, plugins

I've been working on this script that I am using with a WordPress plugin I wrote for our blogs at work. I'm stripping it down to make it a pure jQuery plugin but most of the questions I've seen where for getting the plugin to work like this:

```
$('.some-target').cta();
```

Whereas I want to write it so that the user can do something like:

```
cta();
```

or

```
$.cta
```

I'm not really getting clear answers or seeing many guides covering this, or really if it's possible. In the end I want it to work like it's original iteration for WP, but as a stand alone jQuery plugin for static sites:

```
cta({
  text: "Some Text",
  icon: "Some-icon.jpg",
  dist: 50
});
```

Here is the original code:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){

  cta = function(o) {
    o = o || {};
    var bgColor = o.bgColor;
    var url = o.url;
    var text = o.text;
    var icon = o.icon;
    var buttonText = o.buttonText;
    var target = o.target;
    var dist = o.dist;

    if((o.icon != null) || o.icon == "" ) {
      jQuery('body').append(
        '<div class="cta-popup-wrapper with-icon"><div class="cta-popup"><span class="close-trigger">X</span><img class="cta-icon" src="' + icon + '" alt="Call to Action Icon"><p>' + text + '</p><a class="cta-button" style="background-color:' + bgColor + ';" href="' + url + '">' + buttonText + '</a></div></div>'
      );
    } else {
      jQuery('body').append(
        '<div class="cta-popup-wrapper without-icon"><div class="cta-popup"><span class="close-trigger">X</span><p>' + text + '</p><a class="cta-button" style="background-color:' + bgColor + ';" href="' + url + '">' + buttonText + '</a></div></div>'
      );

    }

    if(target != null) {

      var t = $(target);

      if(t.length) {

        $(window).scroll(function() {

           var hT = t.offset().top,
               hH = t.outerHeight(),
               wH = $(window).height(),
               wS = $(this).scrollTop();

           if (wS > (hT+hH-wH)){
             $('.cta-popup-wrapper').addClass('shown');
           } else {
             $('.cta-popup-wrapper').removeClass('shown');
           }
        });
      }

    } else {
      if((dist != null) && (dist > 0)) {

        var b = $('body').innerHeight();
        dist = dist / 100;
        var trigger = b * dist;

        $(window).scroll(function() {

           var wS = $(this).scrollTop();

           if (wS > trigger){
             $('.cta-popup-wrapper').addClass('shown');
           } else {
             $('.cta-popup-wrapper').removeClass('shown');
           }
        });
      }

    }

  }

});
```

Comment: Are you sure that you need a jQuery plug-in in such case? jQuery plugins usually extend the jQuery object - which is usually bound to a DOM node / collection / Object. - whereas your code seems to not need jQuery at all (if modified the proper way)  (so even better).

Comment: `$.cta = cta` should do it. Bam, jquery plugin.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan  Agreed.  I think all you need is to add a return value from your `cta` function to make it reusable rather than a hardcoded append to the body.

Comment: @KevinB yes, until jQuery releases a super useful `cta` (OK, not so likely...) Method

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I guess you're right. There is a bit more to the function as it finds targets or if no target is set, just uses a distance to determine where to  show the popup/hide it using the scroll method. I'll update it with the rest of the code I have from where I am stripping it down from.

Comment: If you're not using it as `$(...).cta()` then there's no point in making it a jQuery plugin in the first place. There's no significant difference between `cta()` and `$.cta()` except that the latter doesn't clutter the global scope.

Comment: @Barmar Makes sense, appreciate the advice.